# I can't tell why this isn't working. My mouse listener in my JPanel works fine, but my key listener doesn't

Tags: java, jpanel, focus, keylistener, mouselistener

My JPanel has a KeyListener and a MouseListener. The MouseListener works fine, but the KeyListener doesn't work at all. I have never had this problem before. Here is the code of my JPanel and the Main class.

Main:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LevelBuilderFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D Level Builder");
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    LevelBuilderPanel lbp = new LevelBuilderPanel();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setJMenuBar(new Menu());
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(lbp.getSize());
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(new LevelBuilderPanel());
    toolBar.add(new LevelObjectSelector());
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    lbp.setFocusable(true);
    lbp.requestFocusInWindow();
    frame.setSize((int)screenSize.getWidth(), (int)screenSize.getHeight());
    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Panel:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

import Objects.LevelObject;
import Objects.Platform;

public class LevelBuilderPanel extends JPanel implements  KeyListener,             MouseListener,
    MouseMotionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static String levelObject = "";
private int selectedObject;
static boolean selectorTool = false;
private float scale = 1;
private LevelObject lO;
private Rectangle mouseRect;
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
static ArrayList<LevelObject> level = new ArrayList<LevelObject>();

public LevelBuilderPanel() {

    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.scale(scale, scale);

    if (level.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < level.size(); i++) {
            g2.drawImage(level.get(i).getImage(), level.get(i).getX(),
                    level.get(i).getY(), level.get(i).getWidth(), level
                            .get(i).getHeight(), null);
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }
    }

    if (lO != null)
        g2.drawImage(lO.getImage(), lO.getX(), lO.getY(), lO.getWidth(),
                lO.getHeight(), null);

    if (selectorTool)
        g2.draw(level.get(selectedObject).getRect());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i += 10) {
        g2.drawLine(i, 0, i, 2000);
        g2.drawLine(0, i, 2000, i);
    }

}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension((int) (screenSize.getWidth() * 0.90),
            (int) (screenSize.getHeight() * 0.90));
    size.width = Math.round(size.width * scale);
    size.height = Math.round(size.height * scale);
    return size;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (selectorTool) {
        for (int i = 0; i < level.size(); i++) {
            if (mouseRect.intersects(level.get(i).getRect()))
                selectedObject = i;
        }
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = (int) (Math.round((e.getX() + 5) / 10.0) * 10.0) - 10;
    int y = (int) (Math.round((e.getY() + 5) / 10.0) * 10.0) - 10;
    if (levelObject.equalsIgnoreCase("grassPlatform")) {
        level.add(new Platform("Images\\platform.png", x, y, 20, 10, true));
    }
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
    int x = (int) (Math.round((e.getX() + 5) / 10.0) * 10.0) - 10;
    int y = (int) (Math.round((e.getY() + 5) / 10.0) * 10.0) - 10;

    if (selectorTool) {
        for (int i = 0; i < level.size(); i++) {
            if (mouseRect.intersects(level.get(i).getRect()))
                selectedObject = i;
        }
        level.get(selectedObject).setX(x);
        level.get(selectedObject).setY(y);
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getX(), 1, 1);
    int x = (int) (Math.round((e.getX() + 5) / 10.0) * 10.0) - 10;
    int y = (int) (Math.round((e.getY() + 5) / 10.0) * 10.0) - 10;

    if (levelObject.equalsIgnoreCase("grassPlatform")) {
        lO = new Platform("Images\\platform.png", x, y, 20, 10, true);
    } else
        lO = null;
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && selectorTool) {
        level.get(selectedObject).setX(
                level.get(selectedObject).getX() + 10);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && selectorTool) {
        level.get(selectedObject).setX(
                level.get(selectedObject).getX() - 10);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && selectorTool) {
        level.get(selectedObject).setY(
                level.get(selectedObject).getY() - 10);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && selectorTool) {
        level.get(selectedObject).setY(
                level.get(selectedObject).getY() + 10);
    }

    else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && selectorTool) {
        level.remove(selectedObject);
    }
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

static void save(File file) {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < level.size(); i++)
        writer.println(String.valueOf(level.get(i).getName() + " "
                + level.get(i).getImageName() + " " + level.get(i).getX()
                + " " + level.get(i).getY() + " " + level.get(i).getWidth()
                + " " + level.get(i).getHeight() + " "
                + level.get(i).isSolid()));

    writer.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Saved");

}

static void load(File file) {

    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    level.clear();
    while (sc.nextLine() != null) {
        if (sc.next().equals("platform")) {
            level.add(new Platform(sc.next(), Integer.parseInt(sc.next()),
                    Integer.parseInt(sc.next()),
                    Integer.parseInt(sc.next()),
                    Integer.parseInt(sc.next()), Boolean.valueOf(sc.next())));
        }
    }
    sc.close();

}

}
```

Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, the KeyListener just isn't doing anything.